# How do I figure out which version of OpenCL comes with my nvidia-current-dev package?

Tags: 10.04, opencl, nvidia-current-dev

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 with an nvidia geforce GT 240 card. I installed `nvidia-current-dev` with apt-get, thus I got a bunch of headers and lib files for OpenCL. However, I am unable to figure out if I have OpenCL 1.0 or 1.1 (could be 1.2, though I doubt it).

Does anyone know a way to figure out which version of OpenCL comes with the `nvidia-current-dev` package (version: `195.36.24-0ubuntu1~10.04.2`)?

If not, is there another place where I could get an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for OpenCL 1.1 was added to nvidia's official driver in version 280, so anything earlier will support only OpenCL 1.0 (moreover older graphics cards support OpenCL 1.0 even with the latest drivers, but that's not the case with GT240).